# Why for loop output same record repeatedly? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, frontend

I have some testing data:

```
var $data = {
  "pitanje": [{
    "id": 1,
    "naziv": 'Kako se zove najveci bruger',
    "odgovori": [{
      "id": "1",
      "ime": "burger1",
      "tip": "netacno"
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "ime": "burger2",
      "tip": "netacno"
    }, {
      "id": "3",
      "ime": "burger3",
      "tip": "tacno"
    }, {
      "id": "4",
      "ime": "burger4",
      "tip": "netacno"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "naziv": 'Kako se zove najveci bruger king',
    "odgovori": [{
      "id": "1",
      "ime": "burger12",
      "tip": "netacno"
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "ime": "burger13",
      "tip": "netacno"
    }, {
      "id": "3",
      "ime": "burger14",
      "tip": "tacno"
    }],
  }]
};
```

FOR - LOOP:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $data.pitanje.length; i++) {
  $("#kviz").append("<div class='pitanje col-md-12'><h1>" + $data.pitanje[i]['naziv'] + "</h1></div>");

  for (var x = 0; x < $data.pitanje[i]['odgovori'].length; x++) {
    $(".pitanje").append("<li class='odgovor col-md-3'><div data-pitanjeid=" + 
        $data.pitanje[i]['id'] + 
        " data-odgovorid=" + 
        $data.pitanje[i]['odgovori'][x]['id'] +
        ">" + 
        $data.pitanje[i]['odgovori'][x]['ime'] + 
        "</div></li>");
    // console.log($data.pitanje[i]['odgovori'][x]);
  };
};
```

OUTPUT:

```
--Kako se zove najveci bruger--
burger1
burger2
burger3
burger4
**burger12** 
**burger13** 
**burger14**
```

(why this three from second loop is also in first)

```
*Kako se zove najveci bruger king*
burger12
burger13
burger14
```

Comment: Use your browser's development tools to step through the loop.  That will help you debug this properly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that every append one div element with the class `pitanje` for every iteration of your outer loop:

```
$("#kviz").append("<div class='pitanje col-md-12'><h1>" + $data.pitanje[i]['naziv'] + "</h1></div>");
```

In the inner loop you query for `$(".pitanje")`. In the the second iteration of the first loop this will find both `div`s you have created, and will add the append the data to both of them.

You would need to write something like that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $data.pitanje.length; i++) {
  var elementToAppendTo = $("<div class='pitanje col-md-12'><h1></h1><ul></ul></div>");
  elementToAppendTo.find('h1').text($data.pitanje[i]['naziv']);

  $("#kviz").append(elementToAppendTo);

  for (var x = 0; x < $data.pitanje[i]['odgovori'].length; x++) {
    var newItem = $("<li class='odgovor col-md-3'><div></div></li>")
    newItem.find('div').data({
      pitanjeid: $data.pitanje[i]['id'],
      odgovorid: $data.pitanje[i]['odgovori'][x]['id']
    }).text($data.pitanje[i]['odgovori'][x]['ime'])
    elementToAppendTo.find('ul').append(newItem);
    // console.log($data.pitanje[i]['odgovori'][x]);
  }
}
```

An additional note: a `li` element is not a valid child of an `ul`.

Comment: You need to be setting the text of that h1, not just concatenating text into the middle of it.  With what you have in your code, you risk creating invalid HTML and injection.

Comment: @Brad I didn't say that setting the `h1` that way is correct. Thats how the OP wrote the code. I pointed out why the problem happens, and this is because for the second iteration there are two `div`s  with the class `pitanje`.

Comment: I get that, but people copy/paste code from Stack Overflow without paying attention all the time.  It's really not good to have what will effectively become reference code as insecure.  At best, it sets a poor example which you can be sure will be copied by hundreds of people over the next couple years.

Comment: @Brad well that might be true. But how should I reference one part of the code then?

Comment: You were correct... I misunderstood your answer.  In any case, it's resolved now with your suggested code.  My bad.  +1!